# Change Flow to Automate in Sharepoint Online

Tags: flow, microsoft-flow

After change from MS Flow to Automate Microsoft Disabled one test parameter.

Now there are only two test option - Where is the third option?

[image]

How to re-run Workflow with last data?

Please help.

Comment: Which was the 3rd option you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can run test flow with previous run data using 2nd option in the attached screenshot: **Use data from previous runs**.

[image]

For more information, check the official documentation at: [Test flows with previous run data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/April18/microsoft-flow/test-flows-previous-run-data).

Comment: Yes, but there is only 5. And I want more

Comment: And where the third option. Why it is hidden ?

Comment: Can you please tell us the title of the 3rd option you were seeing before? What was it called?